# How can I measure a droplets contact angle without a setup?

Tags: water, surface-chemistry

I have to use a phone camera to replicate the Sessile drop analyzer, but there doesn't seem to be a standard to different parameters, such as how far away should my camera be from the droplet or how much liquid should I use for my droplets? Is it possible to get accurate results this way, and how should I go about it?

Comment: Quick search unveiled [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/s3DrTJk3CFA) which, I guess, uses Bikerman method. The tricky part might be getting the lens attachment, you might need a donor device to harvest the lens from, e.g. a webcam or an old microscope. Probably a magnifying glass will do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2010, Borguet *et al.* published in [*Journal of Chemical Education*, DOI: 10.1021/ed100468u](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed100468u) an intentionally simplified setup which may be useful as a reference.  A Sony Cybershot camera was placed in front of a sample scrutinized under diffuse illumination:

[image]

The additional lens shown is focussed on the drop (both for water and $n$-hexadecane, the authors recommend a volume of $\pu{5 uL}$; focal length of the length used equals $\pu{50 mm}$):[image].

With photos recorded like this

[image]

the contact angle determination was performed with the [contact angle plugin](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/contact-angle.html) of [imageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/).  As [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/), it is open source, free ware, and java based/OS portable.  To quote from their publication:

> For each easurement, the user must choose two points to manually
>   define the baseline and three points along the drop profile (see
>   the supporting information that features a set of instructions
>   supplying all the details on the procedure used to make the
>   measurement). The program then fits the profile of the drop and
>   calculates the contact angle using the sphere approximation
>   or the ellipse approximation. In our study, the ellipse approximation gave consistent results for contact angles $> 40^\circ{}$. For
>   drops with contact angles $< 40^\circ{}$, the sphere approximation was
>   used.

In comparison with reference data, the authors judge contact angles recorded as well as the subsequently calculated surface tensions as good enough for instruction / lab classes and research lab.